# Celery, Django and @shared_task

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to use celery in combination with Django; I have a task in one of my apps and I want to run that with celery. Unfortunately I can not get celery to find the task, and instead I get the following error message in the shell running celery:

```
bash% celery -A webflow worker -l info
-------------- celery@ws v4.4.2 (cliffs)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-4.19.0-8-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-10.3 2020-05-10 11:49:09
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         webflow:0x7f3c8fb483c8
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 32 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . webflow.celery.debug_task

[2020-05-10 11:49:10,261: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2020-05-10 11:49:10,267: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-05-10 10:47:28,942: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'simulation.tasks.unpack_simulation'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
'[["1b9944d2-f874-42d2-9dce-a0387c431b65"], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (115b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 562, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'simulation.tasks.unpack_simulation'
```

The django project is called `webflow` and it has one Django app called `simulation` - all in all the file system look like this:

```
|── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── simulation                   // Django App
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
|   ├── api
|   |    │  
|   │    └── submit.py          // View which (tries) to invoke celery task
│   ├── tasks.py                // Module with celery task
└── webflow                     // Django Project
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── celery.py               // Celery app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── views.py                
    └── wsgi.py
```

The relevant part of the files are:

**simulation/tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task
from simulation.models import Simulation

@shared_task
def unpack_simulation(sim_id):
    simulation = Simulation.objects.get(pk = sim_id)
    simulation.unpack()
```

**webflow/celery.py**

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'webflow.settings')
app = Celery('webflow')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**simulation/api/submit.py**

```
import simulation.tasks


def submit(request):
    ...
    ...
    simulation.tasks.unpack_simulation.delay(sim_id)
```

**webflow/__init__.py**

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

This is my best verbatim reproduction of https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html; I have also tried many minor variations found on the net - but no success. I have tried to grasp the celery documentation about names and imports(https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-naming-relative-imports) - this might be the solution; but I just can got my head around that documentation - sorry.

I don't think my setup is completely broken - if I set `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` in the `webflow/settings.py` file it "works".

I am using Django 3.0.?, Python 3.7 and Celery 4.4.2.

Comment: Is `simulation` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes - `simulation` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: I think that `app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)` should just be `app.autodiscover_tasks()` - from https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html - looking in the code, it seems like the first argument is the packages to discover from, but there are no tasks in your settings file :P

Comment: Thank but I have tried that as well; no cigar :-(

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything else obvious. Make sure you restart celery after making any code changes though, it doesn't autoreload at all.

Comment: Regarding celery restart: It is is enough to Ctrl-C and invoke the shell command again?

Comment: Yes, if your code is up to date. You might want to clear out `__pycache__`, etc.

Comment: When celery starts, it should give you a list of registered tasks, can you update the question with that part of the output?

Comment: Output updated: as you can see things are "consistent" - celery does not print anything about my "missing" task `simulation.tasks.unpack_simulation`

Comment: It's not finding it at all then. So it's not to do with your imports, but to do with discovery. But that's all I can tell from here.

Comment: OK thank you - then I interpret you that I should focus my debugging on the `app.autodiscover_tasks()` call.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:** OK - this was (as expected) 100% my fault, but quite contrived: In the shell where I was running celery I had a envioronment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=some_other_project.settings`

Comment: I am running into issues getting Celery running with Django and am trying to follow where in the OP you had this wrong? Can you expand? Did you change the OP?